# Getting facebook like source information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

Looking at the bottom of [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/) page it would appear that it is possible to get facebook data on where likes are coming from for a particular page.  Unfortunately I can't figure out how to do this.

Ideally I would like a method that doesn't use fql something like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/insights/SOURCE_NAME?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

But if that's not possible I would at least think it is possible to do through fql using something like:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=PAGE_ID AND metric='SOURCE_NAME' AND period = period('month')&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

but this just returns the xml with the error message `Invalid metric name: SOURCE_NAME` for whatever source name I'm trying to use.

What is the proper way to access this data?  Or is facebook just trying to tease me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query I was looking for was something like

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID AND metric='page_fans_by_like_source' AND end_time=end_time_date('YYYY-MM-DD') AND period=period('month')&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this graph API as below:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[page_id]/insights/page_fans_by_like_source/?access_token=?[access]&since=[time_stamp]&until=[time_stamp]
```